Calculate the limit of the integral sum
I was instructed to calculate
$$\mathcal {f} \left( x \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathcal {f}_{n} \left( x \right),$$
where
$$\mathcal {f}_{n} \left( x \right) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac {n x}{{\left( 2 n \right)}^{2} + {\left( k x \right)}^{2}}.$$
I don't even have the faintest idea how to approach this building. Any help would be appreciated.

Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Try rewriting the limit as a Riemann integral.

We want
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{nx}{4n^2 + k^2x^2}\\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x}{4 + (\frac{k}{n})^2x^2}
\end{align}
which is a Riemann sum and hence converting into the integral form we get:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \int_{0}^1 \frac{x \text {d}t}{4 + x^2t^2} \\
&= \int_{0}^x \frac{\text {d}z}{4 + z^2} \qquad (z = xt) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)
\end{align}
